# WebRTC live stream(H264) error in Firefox, can't generate valid SDP answer

Tags: firefox, webrtc, turn, janus-gateway

I am trying to run `H264` encoded live stream in Web Browser using Janus WebRTC Gateway. While testing with `Chrome`, the stream works fine but with `firefox` it shows `ICE failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more details`.

Following is my `about:webrtc` logs for firefox.

```
[ 6442450983 ] http://192.168.2.194:5000/ 15:18:19 GMT+0530 (IST)
PeerConnection ID: 1515491295667117 (id=6442450983 url=http://192.168.2.194:5000/)
ICE Stats
Local Candidate Remote Candidate    ICE State   Priority    Nominated   Selected    Bytes sent  Bytes received
ICE restarts:
ICE rollbacks:
SDP
Local SDP

v=0

o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-57.0.4 3500649212029345392 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0

s=-

t=0 0

a=sendrecv

a=fingerprint:sha-256 11:44:F1:BD:D1:69:8E:17:E0:9A:AA:89:8E:76:9F:4E:09:E1:94:D0:37:34:EE:FE:DF:5E:FC:77:B0:4D:F7:53

a=ice-options:trickle

a=msid-semantic:WMS *

m=video 0 RTP/SAVPF 120

c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0

a=inactive

a=end-of-candidates

a=mid:video

a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000

Remote SDP

v=0

o=- 1515491295396595 1515491295396595 IN IP4 106.51.68.195

s=-

t=0 0

a=sendrecv

a=group:BUNDLE video

a=msid-semantic:WMS janus

m=video 9 RTP/SAVPF 126

c=IN IP4 106.51.68.195

a=candidate:1 1 udp 2013266431 192.168.2.194 45887 typ host

a=candidate:2 1 udp 1677722111 106.51.68.195 45887 typ srflx raddr 192.168.2.194 rport 45887

a=sendonly

a=end-of-candidates

a=fingerprint:sha-256 D2:B9:31:8F:DF:24:D8:0E:ED:D2:EF:25:9E:AF:6F:B8:34:AE:53:9C:E6:F3:8F:F2:64:15:FA:E8:7F:53:2D:38

a=ice-options:trickle

a=ice-pwd:KsS99rsAZXj9lFd7psCT61

a=ice-ufrag:3tcw

a=mid:video

a=rtcp-fb:126 nack

a=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb

a=rtcp-mux

a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000

a=setup:actpass

a=ssrc:3973486276 cname:janusvideo

a=ssrc:3973486276 msid:janus janusv0

a=ssrc:3973486276 mslabel:janus

a=ssrc:3973486276 label:janusv0

RTP Stats
```

I even tried adding following TURN Server

```
{urls: "turn:numb.viagenie.ca",
 username: "l1787875@mvrht.com",
 credential: "test"}
```

But the console error changes to `ICE failed, your TURN server appears to be broken, see about:webrtc for more details`, Keeping the `about:webrtc` logs same as before.

I figured out that somehow Firefox can't generate a valid answer for SDP offer generated by Janus. Created answer by Firefox has attribute `rtpmap: 120 VP8/90000`, whereas SDP offer made by Janus has attribute `rtpmap: 127 H264/90000`, which prevent Firefox to establish a SDP session with Janus. Chrome can generate the valid answer with `rtpmap: 127 H264/90000` so it can display the stream perfectly.

I am using `Mozilla firefox-57.0.4`.
Is there a way, I can get/ generate a valid `SDP answer` for incoming `SDP offer` from Janus?

Comment: It's strange that Chrome works but Firefox doesn't. Go to `about:config` in Firefox and see if `media.peerconnection.ice.relay_only` is set to `true`, which would force Firefox to only establish connections via relay (TURN). If it is, change it to `false` and try again.

Comment: `media.peerconnection.ice.relay_only` is set to its default value only i.e. `false`. Is there anything else I need to check?

Comment: You have pasted the SDP coming from Janus, can you also paste the SDP that Firefox sends? Another thing to try is instead of specifying the TURN, try specifying a public STUN server, e.g. `{ urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }`.

Comment: I am using the STUN server `{ urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }`  and no TURN server. I just used TURN to check for the console error `ICE failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more details` . But it didn't resolve the issue. Things are working fine with Chrome.

Comment: And this is the log from `about:webrtc` in firefox. How can I obtain the SDP, you are asking? I don't have much experience with this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solution worked for me (last yellow message):
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meetecho-janus/jKg5u9421kM

I'm using Janus and I was getting the same error in Firefox.
The problem was about the SDP profile-level-id.
I just had to replace it:

> ```
>             // Create offer/answer now
>              if(jsep === null || jsep === undefined) {
>                      createOffer(handleId, media, callbacks);
>              } else {
>                      if(adapter.browserDetails.browser === "edge") {
>                              // This is Edge, add an a=end-of-candidates at the end
>                              jsep.sdp += "a=end-of-candidates\r\n";
>                      }
>                      var oldsdp = jsep["sdp"];
>                      var pattern=/420029/gi;
>                      var newsdp = oldsdp.replace(pattern,"42e01f");
>                      Janus.log(newsdp);
>                      jsep["sdp"]=newsdp;
>                      config.pc.setRemoteDescription(
>                                      new RTCSessionDescription(jsep),
>                                      function() {
>                                              Janus.log("Remote description accepted!");
>                                              createAnswer(handleId, media, callbacks);
>                                      }, callbacks.error);
>              }
>      }
> ```